# Sublime Text create SASS - Autoprefixer - CSS chain on save without Grunt

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext2, sublimetext, autoprefixer

After watching Chris Coyer's

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7W5unPM_b4&list=UUADyUOnhyEoQqrw_RrsGleA

I was wondering - is it possible to autorun Autoprefixer Sublime plugin right after the CSS file is built and without Grunt? What would I need to configure in Sublime and how?

Ideal chain would be:

Build compressed "style-unprefixed.css" on SASS save - run Autoprefixer - create compressed "style.css"

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but I think I just figured out how to do this, via a shell script.

Prerequisites:

- [SublimeOnSaveBuild](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild) (ST2 Plugin, also works on ST3)
- SASS compiler (I'm using [LibSass/SassC](http://libsass.org/))
- [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) (not the ST plugin)

After all that is taken care of, we'll create the script.  For our purposes, let's call it `buildcss.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# == 0 ]
then 
    echo "Usage: buildcss.sh [scss file] [css file]"
    exit
fi

# Create the css file ($2) from a scss file ($1)
# see "sassc -h" for additional options
sassc $1 $2

# Run autoprefixer, overwrite input .css file
# see "autoprefixer -h" for additional options
autoprefixer -b "> 1%" $2
```

Of course if you're using Ruby SASS (`sass`) instead of `sassc`, the script should be adjusted.

Okay, at this step you should be able to run something like `./buildcss.sh style.scss style.css` to test and make sure that part works.  Then it's just a matter of making Sublime Text run that and pass the correct arguments.

For that, create a custom build system. `Tools > Build System > New Build System...` in ST3. There may be some differences between ST2 and ST3 here, but in ST3 my configuration looks like:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "/path/to/script/buildcss.sh $file ${file_path/scss/css/}/${file_base_name}.css",
    "selector": "source.scss",
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",
}
```

As you may notice, I'm exclusively setting up for scss, but if you need sass you could set up another similar build system, exchanging "sass" for "scss" throughout.  This build system also assumes that you keep your files in a `/scss` subfolder, and that css files should go in a `/css` subfolder at the same level.

And there you have it!  Whenever you save a .scss file, SublimeOnSaveBuild will do it's magic and fire our custom build, which will in turn call the script which calls sassc and autoprefixer.